# Problem reading a data from a file with pandas Python (pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader)

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata, large-data

i want to read a dataset from a file with pandas, but when i use pd.read_csv(), the program read it, but when i want to see the dataframe appears:

**pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader at 0x1b3b6b3e198**

As additional informational the file is too large (around 9 Gigas)

The file use as a separator the vertical lines, and i tried using chunksize but it doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\dguerr\Documents\files\Automotive\target_file", iterator=True, sep='|',chunksize=1000)
```

I want to import my data in the traditional pandas dataframe format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load it chunk by chunk by doing:

```py
import pandas as pd

path_to_file = "C:/Users/dguerr/Documents/Acxiom files/Automotive/auto_model_target_file"
chunk_size = 1000
for chunk in pd.read_csv(path_to_file,chunksize=chunk_size):
     # do your stuff
```

Comment: An error appears: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Try with the new code @DavidMora it should work now

Comment: problem came from the path to file, I changed it

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check encoding types within a DataFrame. Your pd.read_csv defaults to `utf8`, should you be using `latin1` for instance, this could potentially lead to such errors.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/dguerr/Documents/Acxiom files/Automotive/auto_model_target_file',
encoding='latin-1', chunksize=1000)
```

Comment: Instead of providing the answer directly, try writing a comment explaining the solution if it's not too lengthy. @perrier.